# How to trigger UI class for Google Sheets?

Tags: user-interface, google-apps-script, google-sheets

#### My goal

[Here is the documentation I'm trying to follow.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui)

```
// Display a dialog box with a title, message, input field, and "Yes" and "No" buttons. The
// user can also close the dialog by clicking the close button in its title bar.
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var response = ui.prompt('Getting to know you', 'May I know your name?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

// Process the user's response.
if (response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.YES) {
  Logger.log('The user\'s name is %s.', response.getResponseText());
} else if (response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.NO) {
  Logger.log('The user didn\'t want to provide a name.');
} else {
  Logger.log('The user clicked the close button in the dialog\'s title bar.');
}
```

#### What I expect to happen and what happens instead

I expect the UI to display a dialog box with a title, message, input field, and "Yes" and "No" buttons. The user can also close the dialog by clicking the close button in its title bar.

But instead, nothing happens.

#### Steps to reproduce.

1. Open a Google Sheet.
2. Open Script Editor: Tools > Script editor
3. Paste above code into script editor.
4. Close script editor.
5. Navigate to Google Sheet.

But as I mentioned, nothing actually happened.

How do I trigger the UI instance to initiate? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this function:

```
function runIt() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response = ui.prompt('Getting to know you', 'May I know your name?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  if (response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.YES) {
    Logger.log('The user\'s name is %s.', response.getResponseText());
  } else if (response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.NO) {
    Logger.log('The user didn\'t want to provide a name.');
  } else {
    Logger.log('The user clicked the close button in the dialog\'s title bar.');
  }
}
```

After getting the function to run go look at the spreadsheet.

[image]